# pine-script crossunder don't work I expected

Tags: pine-script

I have this problem with enterShortCondition.
I'd want exit short signal when close value is cross under the lower line.

With long position I have no problem but with short condition (it's specular to long condition) I have an exit signals when close prize cross over upper line. I don't understand. I'm crazy with this.

Someone could me help me, please?

Here it is the code

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at ``https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © pret71

//@version=4
strategy("Intraday Forex Strategy", overlay=true)

length = input(20, minval=1)
smaPeriod  = input(defval = 60, title = "SMA Period", type = input.integer)
lower = lowest(length)[1]
upper = highest(length)[1]
basis = avg(upper, lower)
plot(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6A00)
u = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#0094FF)
l = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#0094FF)
mySma=sma(close,smaPeriod)

plot(mySma, "Basis", color=color.red)

//verifico che incaso long sma50 (mySma) sia crescente e in caso short decrescente
confirmLongCondition = iff(mySma[25]>mySma[50] and mySma[0]>mySma[25],true,false)
confirmShortCondition = iff(mySma[25]<mySma[50] and mySma[0]<mySma[25],true,false)

enterLongCondition = crossunder(close,lower) and confirmLongCondition //and (lower>mySma)
if (enterLongCondition)
    strategy.entry("LongEntry", strategy.long)

enterShortCondition = crossover(close,upper) and confirmShortCondition //and (upper<mySma)
if (enterShortCondition)
    strategy.entry("ShortEntry", strategy.short)

exitLongConditiond = crossover(close,upper)
if (exitLongConditiond)
    strategy.close("LongEntry")

exitShortConditiond = crossunder(close,lower)
if (exitLongConditiond)
    strategy.close("ShortEntry")
```

I try to use this pine script but it doesn't work

Comment: It is unnecessary to write `iff(mySma[25]>mySma[50] and mySma[0]>mySma[25],true,false)` as a result of a condition check always returns `true` or `false`. 

Simpler form: `confirmLongCondition = mySma[25]>mySma[50] and mySma[0]>mySma[25]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistyped variable name in your last condition check. You set `exitShortConditiond`, then you are checking against `exitLongConditiond`.

Your code:

```
exitLongConditiond = crossover(close,upper)
if (exitLongConditiond)
    strategy.close("LongEntry")

exitShortConditiond = crossunder(close,lower)
if (**exitLongConditiond**)
    strategy.close("ShortEntry")
```

Comment: oh incredible!!! I read a lot of time to looking for a type error but I didn't see.
thanks